# What is the correct way to tell WebApi2 and EF6 to not serialize a field to Json?

Tags: entity-framework, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, table-per-type

I have an Entity Framework Table per Type hierarchy like this:

```
public class WorkItem
{
    public int WorkItemId {get;set;}
}

public class CancelingWorkItem : WorkItem
{
    public int WorkItemIdToCancel {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("WorkItemIdToCancel")]
    public virtual WorkItem WorkItemToCancel {get;set}
}

public class SomeOtherWorkItem : WorkItem
{
    // more fields...
}
```

When I return a list of all `WorkItems` in the database as Json, any serialized `CancelingWorkItem` will contain the full definition of the `WorkItemToCancel` field. I could just ignore this field with `JsonIgnore`, but I was wondering if there was a different/better way of doing this. My repository project doesn't yet rely on Json.Net, so if I can instead tell the controller not to serialize that field, that might be a better solution.

Comment: Check my answer in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375870/serializing-parent-child-object-to-with-ef-and-webapi/30376142#30376142)

Comment: If you don't want Json.NET attributes on your classes, what about [data contract attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @octavioccl: it seems like that should have worked, but setting lazy loading to be off didn't do anything. I don't want to remove the `virtual` keyword, so I think for now I'm going to use the `IgnoreDataMemberAttribute`.

Comment: Check here: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IgnoreDataMemberAttribute` attribute - It's not from an external library like `JsonIgnore` and I think that the default serializer and Json.NET will both recognise this attribute.

Comment: Also didn't work. So far, the only thing I've found that *did* work 100%, is to use `JsonIgnore` from Json.Net.